# How to make a selective gettext()

Tags: java, swing, select, gettext

I am trying to do a currency exchange program, but if second input(s1 here) is empty, the program gives `NumberFormatException:Empty String error`. It works when first(s here) is empty. So i wonder if there is an alternative way to make it selective with a one button. And why isnt it working when second field is empty ?

```
public class kanvas1 implements ActionListener,WindowListener{


    private JTextField tf;
    private JTextField tf1;
    private JTextField tf2;
    private JTextField tf3;
    private JLabel lb;
    private JLabel lb1;

    private JButton bt;
    private JButton bt1;

    public kanvas1()
    {

        tf=new JTextField();
        tf1=new JTextField();
        tf2=new JTextField();
        tf3=new JTextField();
        lb=new JLabel("$");
        lb1=new JLabel("TL");
        bt=new JButton("Cevir");
        bt1=new JButton("Sıfırla");


        pencere();


    }

    public void pencere() {
        tf.setBounds(50,20,150,50);
        tf1.setBounds(50,80, 150, 50);
        tf2.setBounds(220,20,150,50);
        tf3.setBounds(220,80,150,50);
        lb.setBounds(30,20,20, 50);
        lb1.setBounds(30,80,20,50);
        bt.setBounds(400,20,100, 50);
        bt1.setBounds(400,80,100,50);
        bt.addActionListener(this);
        bt1.addActionListener(this);
        JFrame ab=new JFrame();
        ab.setVisible(true);
        ab.setSize(600,200);
        ab.setLayout(null);
        ab.add(tf);ab.add(tf1);ab.add(tf2);ab.add(tf3);ab.add(bt);ab.add(bt1);ab.add(lb);ab.add(lb1);
        bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                String s=tf.getText(); //problem is here


                double a=Double.parseDouble(s);

                double c=a*5.44;

                String result=String.valueOf(c);

                tf2.setText(result);




            }

        });
        bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {



                String s1=tf1.getText();
                                          //and here

                double b=Double.parseDouble(s1);

                double d=b*0.18;

                String result1=String.valueOf(d);

                tf3.setText(result1);


            }

        });
        bt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                tf.setText("");
                tf1.setText("");
                tf2.setText("");
                tf3.setText("");

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
        System.exit(0);

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new kanvas1();



    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a check before parsing like this:

```
if (s1.isEmpty())
     return;
```

It's failing because `Double.parseDouble(String arg)`  tries to convert the string passed as an argument to a Double that the string represents. which means strings like **"12", "12.0", etc.** are valid inputs while Strings like **"12a", "ac", "", etc**. are bound to fail; because, after all, `12a` is not a double(its not even a number!).

If a text Field is empty and you execute `getText()` what you will retrieve is `""` (an Empty String) and not `null`.

so, if you want to make any conditional decision, base your condition on the text retrieved being `empty i.e. ""` and not `null`

Comment: But i tried  if(s1!=null)then parsing it didnt work why?

Comment: because `String s1 = ""` does not make `s1` null, it makes `s1` empty (s1 holds empty string). if you do `String s1 = null`  (it doesn't hold any string) is when your case would work.

Comment: And also it was working when first input was empty i mean s is null s1 is not.

Comment: @TARIK did you get what I am saying?

Comment: Yes i understand. i actually knew what was the problem not the solution.But my question is different and i couldn't asked it properly, i think. Anyway thanks for the answer it is enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `addActionListener` for the same button twice like, you can write it in the single `addActionListener`. 
**Also, avoid keeping any field empty, you are getting `NumberFormatException` as one of your `JTextField` is giving the blank value or any other value which is not a double. While parsing with Double.parseDouble("12.34") should always contain the double value in string format. Parsing with rest other values throws `NumberFormatException`**

```
bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        String s=tf.getText(); //problem is here


        double a=Double.parseDouble(s);

        double c=a*5.44;

        String result=String.valueOf(c);

        tf2.setText(result);




    }

});
bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {



        String s1=tf1.getText();
                                  //and here

        double b=Double.parseDouble(s1);

        double d=b*0.18;

        String result1=String.valueOf(d);

        tf3.setText(result1);


    }

});
```

Replace above code with:

```
bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        String s=tf.getText();


        double a=Double.parseDouble(s);

        double c=a*5.44;

        String result=String.valueOf(c);

        tf2.setText(result);



         String s1=tf1.getText();
         double b=Double.parseDouble(s1);

        double d=b*0.18;

        String result1=String.valueOf(d);

        tf3.setText(result1);



    }

});
```